# Modified rat in a maze

Tags: java, algorithm

It was asked me in an interview.you have given a m*n matrix filled with "1" and "0"."1" means you can use the cell and "0" means the cell is blocked.you can move in 4 directions left, right, top, bottom.every time you move upward direction or downward it cost you  1$.moving left or right will not be added to cost.so you have to write a code to check whether one can reach to destination index (x,y) starting from (0,0). If yes then print the minimum cost if no then print "-1".

I am not able to calculate the cost.
Here is my code

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static int dest_x = 0;
    static int dest_y = 0;
    static int cost = 0;
    static int m = 0;
    static int n = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Test rat = new Test();
        int maze[][] = {
                {1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 1}
        };
        dest_x = in.nextInt();
        dest_y = in.nextInt();
        m = in.nextInt();
        n = in.nextInt();
        if (rat.solveMaze(maze))
            System.out.println("YES");

        else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
        System.out.println("cost = " + cost);
    }

    boolean isSafe(int maze[][], int x, int y) {
        // if (x,y outside maze) return false
        return (x >= 0 && x < m && y >= 0 &&
                y < n && maze[x][y] == 1);
    }

    boolean solveMaze(int maze[][]) {
        int sol[][] = {{0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };

        if (!solveMazeUtil(maze, 0, 0, sol)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean solveMazeUtil(int maze[][], int x, int y, int sol[][]) {
        // if (x,y is goal) return true
        if (x <= dest_x || y <= dest_y)
            if (x == dest_x && y == dest_y) {
                sol[x][y] = 1;
                return true;
            } else if (sol[x][y] == 1) {
                return false;
            }

            // Check if maze[x][y] is valid
            else if (isSafe(maze, x, y)) {
                // mark x,y as part of solution path
                sol[x][y] = 1;

                // Move forward in x direction 
                if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol)) {
                    //System.out.println("here at x+1 x = " + x  + " y = " + y);
                    return true;
                }

                // Move down in y direction 
                if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol)) {
                    //System.out.println("here at y+1 x = " + x  + " y = " + y);
                    cost++;
                    return true;
                }
                cost--;
                if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol)) {
                    // System.out.println("here at x-1 x = " + x  + " y = " + y);  
                    return true;
                }
                if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol)) {
                    //System.out.println("here at y-1 x = " + x  + " y = " + y);  
                    cost++;
                    return true;
                }
                cost--;
                /* If no solution then
                   BACKTRACK: unmark x,y as part of solution
                   path */
                sol[x][y] = 0;
                return false;
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the maze into a *Directed Graph* and solve *shortest path* problem

1. Cells which are marked by `"1"` are *nodes* (marked by `"0"` should be ignored)
2. If we can move from one cell (node) to another, connect them with a directed *edge*; put *cost* (`0` or `1`) on the edge (please, notice, that we have a multigraph: two nodes can be connected with *two* different edges).
3. Finally, with a help of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) find the *shortest path* (i.e. *min cost*) between required nodes.

Comment: How to convert the matrix into directed graph.Use of collection class is not allowed.

Comment: @Pmanglani: As far as I can see from your code `boolean solveMazeUtil(...int sol[][])` *arrays* are allowed; you can *treat* the initial `int maze[][]` as the graph: you do have *nodes* (items marked by `1`) and you can compute edges *dynamically* (check 4 cell's neighbours)

Comment: It's really a graph. Also, rather than cells being nodes, sets of horizontally contiguous "1" cells should be nodes. I.e., the row 000111000111000 has 2 nodes. Represent the graph as an adjacency matrix. Run BFS stopping when you get to the destination.